# Перпендикулярные стрелки

Tags: python

Определите какое наименьшее число полных минут пройдет к тому моменту, когда часовая и минутная стрелки расположатся на циферблате перпендикулярно друг другу. Например, если это произойдет через 15 минут 50 секунд, то выдать надо 15.

Вещественную арифметику, условный оператор и циклы использовать запрещено.

Входные данные

На вход программе подаются два целых числа n,m (0<n≤12, 0≤m<60), указывающие момент времени "n часов m минут".

Comment: Начните решать, покажите свои попытки

Answer (score 0):

Берём формулу из [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_angle_problem).

```
# вычисление угла между стрелками часов для указанного времени
def get_clock_hands_angle(hours, minutes):
    return (hours*60 - minutes*11) / 2

# вычисление ближайших минут для заданного часа и угла между стрелками
def get_minutes_for_angle(hours, angle):
    return int((hours*60 - angle*2) / 11)

def calc_new_time_for_90_angle(hours, minutes):
    curr_angle = get_clock_hands_angle(hours, minutes)
    # ближайший 90-градусный угол относительно найденного
    expected_angle = (int(curr_angle + 90) // 180) * 180 - 90
    expected_minutes = get_minutes_for_angle(h, expected_angle)
    delta_minutes = expected_minutes - minutes  # собственно, искомый результат

    expected_hours = hours
    # этот if не считается, он только для распечатки времени, что не требовалось в задаче
    if expected_minutes > 59:
        expected_hours = (expected_hours + 1) % 12
        expected_minutes -= 60

    print(f"""
    Время: {hours:2}:{minutes:02}
    Текущий угол: {curr_angle:3.1f}
    Ожидаемый угол: {expected_angle:3}
    Ожидаемое время: {expected_hours:2}:{expected_minutes:02}
    Должно пройти минут: {delta_minutes}""")
    return delta_minutes

h = int(input("Введите часы   (1 - 12): "))
m = int(input("Введите минуты (0 - 59): "))

h %= 12  # 12 часов - это 0

calc_new_time_for_90_angle(h, m)
```